# React router dom not loading data when url is entered manually but redirects fine when clicking on the link directly (Dynamic Segment)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

Im using the new react-router-dom (6.16) format that Ive gotten from using their docs, this is my index.tsx:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <NavBar />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Home />
      },
      {
        path: "/bands/:bandId",
        element: <Band />,
      },
      {
        path: "/basket",
        element: <Basket />
      },
    ]
  }
])

const container = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.createRoot(container as Element).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

Within my NavBar I have some links within my code:

```
<NavDropdown.Item>
  <Link to={`bands/1`}>20Kg</Link>
</NavDropdown.Item>
```

When I click on the link it redirects to the correct route and displays the component as I would like it to look (http://localhost:8081/bands/1). However when I enter the link manually (exactly the same route http://localhost:8081/bands/1) it displays an empty page.

Also when I enter routes like `http://localhost:8081/basket` manually they seem to work fine which leads me to think its a dynamic segment issue.

In the console, Im getting these errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8081/bands/bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Having looked through the React-Router docs and especially the tutorial, it seems I may need a loader underneath `element: <Band />` but I cant seem to get any luck.

My current attempt to fix this has been to add an async function in the form of a loader and importing it to my index.tsx file. This is what my band.tsx file starts off as:

```
export async function loader({ request }: any) {
  const selectedBand = await getBand(params.bandId);
  return selectedBand
}

export default function Band() {
  const { selectedBand }: any = useLoaderData();
// rest of code using selected Band
```

and a `getBand` function that looks like this:

```
import bandsData from "../bandsData.json";

export async function getBand(id) {
  const bands = bandsData.bands;
  const band = await bands.find((band) => band.id === id);
  return band ?? null;
}
```

This doesn't work but I wanted to know if Im on the right track with using the loader and if Im close using this method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you building and serving/hosting the app? The basic gist is that you need to configure the server or hosting service to return the root index.html file for all page requests into the app.

Comment: If you mean what script im running to see the app, im using npm start which is "webpack serve --mode development --open"

Comment: I guess in this case it might be your webpack configuration if you are just serving it locally.

Comment: Ive had a look through my webpack.config and it seems to be sound, Ive added the important bits to my question

Comment: @drew-reese was right, in the end I forgot to add `const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');` in my webpack.config.

After installing `html-webpack-plugin` and adding it to plugins directed at index.html it now works!